# Fail to import ova file to VMware Player

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, ova

I downloaded an OVA file from [SDN-Hub](http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/sdn-tutorial-vm/), and used VMWare Player 11 to import it.

It came out with this error message:

```
Error while converting to a virtual machine:
Line 96:Unsupported element 'StorageItem'
Line 105:Unsupported element 'StorageItem'
Line 114:Unsupported element 'EthernetPortItem'
```

It's weird, because I downloaded the same file a few months ago in my other computer, and it worked well.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Seems the problem is related to the OVF format, the virtual machine was exported using OVF 2.0

What I did to import it to vmware was to import the sdn-hub vm into virtual box and export it again using OVF format 1.0.

Then vmware was happy importing the machine, and just works fine

Comment: It's a pity they haven't fixed this, after 4 years (not sure whether it's VirtualBox or VMWare at fault).

Comment: Still a problem in 2022.

Comment: Even extracting vmdk from ovf doesn't work! It will be read only file system, no way to fix this

Comment: vmware should have this in their docs stupid of them to rely on third party online forums......

Answer (score 0):

When you go to export from the virtual box, it gives you the option to choose a format; 0.9 or 1.1 versions. I chose v1.1 for my CSI Linux ova on the virtual machine and it was converted straight to another ovs file of the format I chose and to a dir of my choice. I then uploaded this into my VMware Workstation Player 17 and it is working perfectly.

GM.